# Microsoft Framework Update (KB4054981) Causing Issues With Crystal Reports 13 Not Displaying

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, asp.net, crystal-reports

Per the title, I am having issues getting a Crystal Report to display on my website. Here are the necessary details:

- Microsoft security and quality update for framework 4.6/4.7 was applied to a server the night prior. We know that this is the culprit because once the update was rolled back, with no other solutions applied to the server code, the website was displaying Crystal Report pages correctly.
- Team verified that the aspnet_client/system_web folder that the server was looking for was present in the website directory and had the necessary files within. Also checked user computers to see if their computers were looking for similar files.
- Team restarted IIS and verified that necessary permissions were granted for users to the crystal report files.
- Team was receiving the "bobj is undefined" error when locally debugging until the specific aspnet_client/system_web folder was added to the solution (software code error).
- Team was receiving errors surrounding the crv.js and style.css files not being found until the specific aspnet_client/system_web folder was added to the solution.
- Team has tried to add specific < SectionGroup > and < Section > code for Crystal Reports in the webconfig file as detailed by several Stack Overflow answers--none of which worked to resolve the problem (software code proposed solution).

**How, and in what way, does the Microsoft update interfere with Crystal Reports 13 on the server?** My knowledge of the way updates interact with one another is limited, so I am not sure how I can fix Crystal Reports while keeping this update installed.

Please let me know if anyone needs additional information or if I need to post this question elsewhere.

Comment: It is going to be difficult for us to determine, how the update interferes with Crystal Report, outside of what you have already told us.  It's not clear what you are looking for exactly.  The update is nearly 2 months old.  Have you tried the patch that replaces KB4054981?

Comment: The only possible change that could be releated to your problems, is the changes to how cookies are handled, check the guidance on the [patch](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4054981) to ensure the response cookie is not being removed.

Comment: Thank you for responding. I suppose I am looking for why this particular update interferes with Crystal Reports 13. I have not tried that particular patch. Usually the network team handles updates for our server, so I am not sure if I actually can forgo this update and just use the patch. I will have to ask.

Answer (score -1):

I also had a specific program quit working after ONE update installed. KB4054852 it caused two needed programs to quit working overnight after the update, i simply uninstalled the update, rebooted and it worked.  this time it was easy, last time it took me 6 hours to figure it out by uninstalling one at a time. Good Luck sir. Mitchell Parks

Comment: This does not answer the author's question.  The author already determined that removing the update fixes the problem.  The author wants to patch security flaws, patched by this particular update, the author is looking for an acceptable solution (removing the update does not meet that requirement).  If it does by some chance, meet the requirement, then the question isn't clear.

Comment: KB4054852 is a 3 month old patch.  It also is a completely different patch altogether and is unrelated to the author's issue.